# cp: cannot create regular file:

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Hi I'm trying to install ETHNOS, a programming environment for the design of a real time control system composed of different robots, devices and external supervising or control stations.
Installing instruction are simple:
cd source
make
make install

but when i use make install then it says:

```
cp *.h /usr/include
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/broadrx.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/broadtx.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etconst.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etctlmsg.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etexpert.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etkernel.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etmasks.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etmemory.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etmsg.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etmsgbmb.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/etsubsched.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/ettimer.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/exception.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/libsock.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/mastersocket.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/sockexrx.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/sockextx.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/trace.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/include/trace_generic.h': Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Comment: did you try `sudo make install` ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have permission to create files in /usr/include. Typically this means you need to be root. When installing you normally need to run `make; make test; sudo make install`. The sudo runs the command provided as its arguments as the super-user (aka root).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running the command as root?

`sudo make install`

Answer (score 2):

run make install as root

> sudo make install